# Tensorflow Multiple Graph & Patch Concern

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, deep-learning

I have a situation where I am using two different networks, one network to tell me if there is important information in a given patch, and a second network to tell me where the important information in the patch is using segmentation.

If I operate them in the same TF Graph / Session, I end up having to use tf.where or tf.cond to tell me which patches I actually want to use, but my optimizer is creating gradients for each condition for the whole net, or at least that is my working theory.

This is using `segmentation_logit = tf.where(is_useful_patch,coarse_log,negative_log)`
Negative log is a tensor of 0's in the same shape as the coarse logit.

If I am using 192 (128x128) patches, the optimizer attempts to create a parameter with over 100 million parameters (ex: [192,222,129,128]), which nukes my GPU ram and causes a crash.

So, short of actually defining two different sessions, graphs, savers, restorers and tensorboard writers, is there a better way to go about this, a better way to calculate gradients, or a way to combine multiple graphs in the same session?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm supposing you get a 192 long `is_useful_patch` vector with values between 0 and 1 (probabilities) as a result of the first network.

First of all, forget `tf.cond` of `tf.where`. I suggest to take a smaller number, like 16 or so (or whatever is best based on your experience, how many useful patches there are normally), and take the index of the best 16 patches with [`tf.nn.top_k`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k) like this:

```
values, idx_best_patches = tf.nn.top_k( is_useful_patch,
    k = 16, sorted = False, name = 'idx_best_patches' )
```

Then use to collect the best patches with [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) like this:

```
best_patches = tf.gather_nd( patches, idx_best_patches, name = 'best_patches' )
```

This will collect your best 16 patches and then you continue only with those 16 into the segmenter, instead of 192, having just cut the memory requirement for the segmenter to 1/12. This is the core of the idea.

If there are less than 16 patches with useful information, you can mask some of the output. Also I have no idea how your patches are structured, so make sure you review the [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) parameters for correctness, it can be tricky.

Comment: While not perfect, I think this might be the easiest thing to do. I wasn't aware of top_k.

I was running into an efficiency where the optomizer was generating a gradient storage variable for each patch.

I'm going to do the top_k, but long term I'll probably be working towards two separate networks.

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, good luck with it! Would you mind accepting my answer then?